# How to prevent a method of a class to be called before the class is ready?

Tags: c#, class, methods, locking

Here is my custom "logger" class, which helps me create logs file in my project.

```
namespace MyProject
{
class Logger
{
    private FileInfo fFile;
    private DirectoryInfo dDir;

    /// <summary>Add a new entry to the log file.</summary>
    /// <param name="sData">The line to add.</param>
    public void Add(string sData)
    {
        DateTime CurrTime = DateTime.Now;

        if (fFile.Length > 1048576)
        {
            fFile.MoveTo(Path.Combine(dDir.FullName, CurrTime.ToShortDateString() + fFile.Name));
            fFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dDir.FullName,fFile.Name));
            using (StreamWriter sw = fFile.CreateText())
            {
                sw.WriteLine("{0:u}|{1}", CurrTime, sData);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = fFile.AppendText())
            {
                sw.WriteLine("{0:u}|{1}", CurrTime, sData);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Logger instance</summary>
    /// <param name="sFile">Full name of the file to use as logs. Ex : "MyLogs.txt"</param>
    public Logger(string sFile)
    {
        dDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(MyProject.AppPath, "logs"));
        if (!dDir.Exists)
        {
            dDir.Create();
        }

        fFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dDir.FullName,sFile));

        if (!fFile.Exists)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = fFile.CreateText())
            {
                sw.WriteLine("{0:u}|Logger Started", DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Add("Logger Started");
        }           
    }
}
}
```

The problem I have with this code is, apparently, sometimes, Logger.Add is called before the new instance of that logger had time to create the file. So my program crashes saying "file not found", although, the file ends up being created in the end, and if I restart my program using the same filename for the logs, everything works fine (because the file exists now ...)

Instead of just making sure logger.add is not called before the file is created, is there a way to "lock" the class ?

I've tried the lock method but it didn't work ... Lock(this) didn't do anything, and I can't use it on the method itself.

Comment: can you try `if file.exists` and if it doesn't exist, run `system.threadding.threadding.sleep(10)` and try again.  It's a bit of a hack, but it will basically make your application "wait" before executing the add method.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - This would work as the code needs to still create the file before the second thread calls the method. If both threads sleep for 10 milliseconds they could still collide.

Comment: This is completely out of left field, but it may be worth looking at Log4Net to see how the do logging.  Use the wheels that are out there instead of re-inventing them ;-).  Of course, this is under the assumption that you haven't already tried this.  Please disregard this comment and accept my apologies if that assumption is incorrect.

Comment: I haven't looked at log4net, I don't want to re-invent the wheel, but since I'm still learning c#, I wanted to do what I'd consider "simple" stuff myself ... although this might indeed be more complicated than what I thought.

Comment: Could you post enough code to reproduce the problem? Or at the very least the stack trace from the exception? It's still not clear what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is actually caused not because the file doesn't exist, but because the FileInfo instance is stale! You created the FileInfo when the file didn't exist, and it takes a snapshot of the state of the file at this time. When I test it the exception is getting thrown when you invoke `fFile.Length` in the Add method. If I add in a call to `fFile.Refresh()` I find it works:

```
...
DateTime currTime = DateTime.Now;
fFile.Refresh();
if (fFile.Length > 1048576)
...
```

See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh.aspx

"Calls must be made to Refresh before attempting to get the attribute information, or the information will be outdated."

Answer (score 2):

The poblem is that the IO operation has been cached. This theoretically shouldn't be a problem but practically it is.

You can call sw.Flush() in your constructor. That will force the file from the cache to the disk and therefore to create the file.

```
if (!fFile.Exists) 
{ 
    using (StreamWriter sw = fFile.CreateText()) 
    { 
        sw.WriteLine("{0:u}|Logger Started", DateTime.Now); 
        sw.Flush();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I wouldn't go this route, with locking the class. I would take the code out which creates the log file and make it its own method. Then when the add method is called, add in some logic to check to see if the log file exists (this logic should also be its own method, in my opinion). If the file exists, continue on with logging, if not then create the log file (using the method you extracted above), then once that method returns successfully, go ahead and write your log.

Comment: I think this is probably what I'm going to do, I didn't do that from the start because I was hoping to get away with just doing the checking once... But a few more milliseconds to run that code are worth it if it avoids a crash :)

Answer (score 1):

In the method, check if the class "is ready" (whatever that may be) and if it's not either wait, return an error or whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You might attempt using the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class and handle events to make the class ready. That way the event could be added as a delegate and would only be called once the file in question was created. Thread.Sleep might be processor intensive and cause other processes to lock up while this process is expecting to complete.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor you are setting the field fFile and dDir, instead you should have a field that is a streamwriter, and use THAT in the Add method.

Comment: I'll look into that, although, unless I'm wrong, that wouldn't solve my problem of the Add method being called before the file is created, and having my program to crash.

Comment: I think this would fix your problem. This can't fail with a file-not-found error during writing because file-not-found only happens when *opening* the file.

Comment: To be absolutely sure that this would fix your problem, I'd need to know where the crash is actually happening.  But from reading the code, I'd say it's happening in the "else" clause of your if statement in the Add method.  The problem is that Add method is being called before the file system gets updated -- this wouldn't be a problem if you were using the same streamwriter.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prevent your add method from running before the file is created - you can do this using an EventWaitHandle or perhaps some other thread control mechanism (perhaps using the monitor class).

And also restrict usage of the file to one thread at a time using `Lock`, you don't want two threads running `Add` at the same time - and both trying to move the file at once.

```
EventWaitHandle _handle = new EventWaitHandle (false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
Object _fileLock = new Object();


 public Logger(string sFile)
{

// Do as you do here

_handle.Set();
}


public void Add(string sData)
{
    _handle.WaitOne ();    // Blocks the thread untill Set() is called on _handle


    Lock(_fileLock){    // Only one thread may enter at a time
       // Do as you do already
    }

}
```

On second thought, using `Lock(_fileLock){` around your ctor code should do the same job as the WaitHandle.

Answer (score 1):

The class is supposed to be ready when its constructed as fas as the compilers job is concerned. Beyond that any logic will have to be programmed.

```
    fFile.MoveTo(Path.Combine(dDir.FullName, CurrTime.ToShortDateString() + fFile.Name));
    fFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dDir.FullName,fFile.Name));
```

This looks like the race condition and needs to be serialized. We had one off issues even after using locks (perl/log4perl) and ended up preferring separate log files for each of the processes.
Unless there are multiple Logger objects alive (even across processes since we are dealing with files) it should not be an issue.

Wonders, isn't there a log4 equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT - *I wrote this on a Linux machine when I didn't have a C# compiler around. Having tested the code on a Windows machine I've found the problem observed here is in fact much simpler than my speculation. See my other answer.*

Are you using multiple threads here? If you are, you're going to need to take a different approach. For example, you will suffer from race conditions if two threads attempt to call Add at the same time and one or both attempt to move the file.

Can any other process move or lock your log-file while your program is running, and if they do, does your program need to not crash? If that is the case, you're going to need to change a lot, since all of your file I/O operations might fail.

If *neither* of these cases apply, then it looks like your problem is that the file is stored on some file system that exhibits some amount of latency between you creating a file and you being able to observe that file. I did not think this was the case with NTFS or FAT32. Are you storing the log file on a network share? Without knowing more, I can't think of much better to do than employing rockinthesixstring's suggestion of testing if the file exists and if not using a short Sleep() call until it does (or until you've waited long enough that it's clear something has gone wrong - maybe somebody deleted the file from under you).

Note that if the problem *is* related to the file system, no amount of locking in the class is going to help, nor will calling Flush because the "using" statement ensures that the StreamWriter has been disposed, which will close the file in addition to having much the same effect as Flush, so a Flush is redundant.

All that said, why are you closing the file and opening it again all the time? Is it to make sure nothing goes missing if your program crashes? If so, you are probably better off following jmoreno's advice to keep a TextWriter open, but to call Flush on it after you write each line.

Comment: I'm using the "using" construct because that's how it is in the example on MSDN, and I thought that construct was more readable and easy to use.

I don't know why the file is not created "quick enough". I'm running the program on my laptop...